# MySQL giving an error on a query that seemed to run fine on workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

Query that retrives strigified json data:

```
select count(*) from ABC 
where NOT(StoredFileLinks = '[]' or StoredFileLinks LIKE %xtractedImages\": []%') 
and NOT(Response LIKE 'Unable to detect%' or Response LIKE 'Your device is not%');
```

Can't seem to understand where the error is. It says:

`pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select count(*) from ABC where NOT(StoredFileLinks = '[]' or StoredFileLinks LIKE %xtractedImages": []%') and NOT(Response LIKE 'Unable to detect%' or Response LIKE 'Your device is not%');': (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'%xtractedImages": []%\') and NOT(Response LIKE \'Unable to detect%\' or Response LI\' at line 1')`

The same query runs on MySQL workbench with V8.04. This query is being used in ubuntu server whose mysql version is 14.14.

Where does the error lie?

Comment: "MySQL version 14.14" not exists. Show FULL version information.

Comment: Single quotes wrapped the pattern in the first LIKE is lost.

Comment: @Akina it showed me this on ```mysql -V``` command ```mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.28, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper```

Comment: Your MySQL version is `5.7.28`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first `like` condition is not constructed properly.

```
select count(*) from ABC 
where not(StoredFileLinks = '[]' or StoredFileLinks like '%xtractedImages": []%') 
and not(Response LIKE 'Unable to detect%' or Response like 'Your device is not%');
```

Comment: got it. thanks. Big query so couldn't grab the error.